# Plotly Treemap: Make color consistent with value

Tags: python, visualization, treemap, plotly-python

I want to set the variables value and color to the same column when generating a treemap with plotly.express.

```py
fig = px.treemap(df,
                 path=sti,
                 values='Size in kB',
                 color='Size in kB',
                 branchvalues='total')
```

This does not work as expected. Only the innermost "children" in the treemap are actually given the appropriate color, and the parents of the child are assigned a seemingly random value (not a sum, average, or value of any child).

I would like the color of a parent to be colored according to the sum of its children. Oddly, plotly seems to create a new value called `<column_name>_sum`, which is the value I need, but I can't access it - I can only see it when hovering. Any help?

[image]

Comment: I tried to find a way to do your request using the official [sample](https://plotly.com/python/treemaps/#treemap-of-a-rectangular-dataframe-with-continuous-color-argument-in-pxtreemap). This example is for the population of each continent, with the population specified as the color and value, and the color map changed to a continuous blue color map. I have also disabled the coloring weights for the population.

Comment: Expand the code in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1w4js0dMGNMrnzYQ2wntK4gUpYOXgleEi?usp=sharing).  You can check and remove it if it is not what you expect.

Comment: @r-beginners, it seems that you have replicated the issue. I don't understand if you have found a solution or not, but if yes, then it is not apparent from the notebook you are linking to :/ In your notebook, I would expect "Asia" to have a darker color than China, because more people live in Asia than in China, but that is not the case. Did you find a way to do it like that?

Comment: I did not present a solution, but rather the limitations of Treemap. We can distinguish colors by continent and within continents. I believe your desired output would have been if the colors of China were the colors of Asia, as you have commented.